# Add items to a shopping cart in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, shopping-cart

Angular beginner here.
I'm trying to create a shopping cart for college.
I need to add the name and price in a text input and after clicking a button the item is supposed to be added to a list.
The thing is that whenever I press the button nothing happens, and I'm lost since the console doesn't tell me anything about what could be wrong. So, here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app = "myApp">
<head>
    <title>Shopping Cart</title>
    <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js">     </script>
    <script src = "app.js"></script>        
</head>
<body ng-controller = "myShoppingCart">

            <h1>Add to cart</h1>
            <form >
                    <p>Product: <input type = "text" ng-model = "nameProduct"></p>
                    <p>Price: <input type = "number" min = "0" step = "any" ng-model = "priceProduct"></p>
                    <input type = "submit" value = "Add" ng-click = "addProduct()">
            </form>

        </div>

        <div">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat = "product in products">
                    <span>{{product.name}}</span>
                    <span>{{product.price}}</span>
                    <span><input type = "number" min = "0" placeholder = "0" value = "0" ng-model = "amount"></span>
                    <span>{{product.price*amount}}</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is my js code:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller('myShoppingCart', function($scope) {

 $scope.products = [];

 function addProduct() {

    $scope.productos.push({nombre:$scope.nameProduct, price:$scope.priceProduct});
    $scope.nameProduct = "";
    $scope.priceProduct = "";
 }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have pushed the values to wrong object . 
and also you need to change lot .and your button click should be need write to

```
 $scope.addProduct= function () {
//code
}
```

So please copy and past my code to instead of your code

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app = "myApp">
<head>
    <title>Shopping Cart</title>
    <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js">     </script>
    <script src = "app.js"></script>        
</head>
<body ng-controller = "myShoppingCart">

            <h1>Add to cart</h1>
            <form >
                    <p>Product: <input type = "text" ng-model = "nameProduct"></p>
                    <p>Price: <input type = "number" min = "0" step = "any" ng-model = "priceProduct"></p>
                    <input type = "submit" value = "Add" ng-click = "addProduct()">
            </form>

        </div>

        <div>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat = "product in products">
                    <span>{{product.name}}</span>
                    <span>{{product.price}}</span>
                    <span><input type = "number" min = "0" placeholder = "0" value = "0" ng-model = "amount"></span>
                    <span>{{product.price*amount}}</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

### and JS Code

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller('myShoppingCart', function($scope) {

 $scope.products = [];

$scope.addProduct= function () {

    $scope.products.push({name:$scope.name, price:$scope.priceProduct});
    $scope.nameProduct = "";
    $scope.priceProduct = "";
 }

});
```

Comment: You were right, it indeed fixed my issue. 
I changed my function declaration to what you suggested me and worked just fine. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type = "submit" value = "Add" ng-click = "addProduct()">
```

Needs to be

```
<input type = "button" value = "Add" ng-click = "addProduct()">
```

Submit will submit the form to the server, not exactly what you're looking for I guess.

Also, bad typo here:

```
 <div">
```

And here (products, not productos):

```
$scope.productos
```

Comment: And `nombre` should be `name`

Comment: Thanks, I changed submit to button and form to div, although it did not fixed my problem.
The other two errors were not present in my original code, since my program is not originally written in English, so I had to translate it and erase some styling unrelated to the issue.

Comment: The button click is does not call, Because angular js needs to call `$scope.functionname= function (){//code}` ...see my answer